# How to create new variable from For Loop results

Tags: variable, forloop

I need to get a list of all the "sizes" from my Table type field column. The list of sizes needs to be separated by a "|"... eg: small|medium|large

My Table type field name is "productAttributes" and the column in that field is "size".

How can I string together the results of a For Each loop to create a new variable with Twig?

Comment: For what it's worth... Selvin taught me how to do this once but I can't remember!

Comment: Do you want this in PHP or Twig? Is this a custom table for a plugin.

Comment: For Twig... This is data stored in a "Table" field type... not a custom plugin.

Comment: might be worth clarifying this in the question so it is more useful for people viewing this in future...

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then you should be able to do it as follows:

```
{% set sizes = [] %}

{% for productAttribute in entry.productAttributes %}
    {% set sizes = sizes|merge([productAttribute.size]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% set sizes = sizes|join('|') %}
```

The `sizes` variable will then be a string containing the pipeline separated sizes, for example:

```
small|medium|large
```

Comment: Thank you Ben. This is what I needed and did the trick perfectly!